# Script about Restricting Days in WPForms

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, date

Im trying to select from day 8 since today, but can't get to this and time is coming to an end.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction on what's wrong with my code?

```
<script>
 
      // Find out the current time
      var now = new Date();
 
      // Take that current time and round it up so we have an even number on the interval
      now.setHours( now.getHours() + Math.round(date.getMinutes()/90) );
        
      window.wpforms_999_8 = window.wpforms_999_8 || {};
      window.wpforms_999_8.timepicker = {
         forceRoundTime: true,
 
         // Disable any times that have passed already and return the new time selections
         minTime: now+8.toLocaleTimeString()
      };
      
      new customDatePicker();
} );
</script>
```

Comment: This one worked perfect at Ninja Forms:

``<script>
jQuery(document).ready( function( $ ) {
var customDatePicker = Marionette.Object.extend( {
initialize: function() {

this.listenTo( Backbone.Radio.channel( 'flatpickr' ), 'init', this.modifyDatepicker );
},
modifyDatepicker: function( dateObject, fieldModel ) {
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 7);
dateObject.set("minDate", tomorrow );
}
});


new customDatePicker();
} );
</script>``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked like a charm:

```
function wpf_dev_limit_date_picker() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.wpforms_3017_9 = window.wpforms_3017_9 || {};
    window.wpforms_3017_9.datepicker = {
        disableMobile: true,
        // Don't allow users to pick before 8th day from today
        minDate: new Date().fp_incr(+8),
        }
</script>
<?php
```